# Volunteer Report Throws "DB Error: unknown error"

Tags: civivolunteer, reports

Seemingly no matter what options I choose on the Volunteer Report it throws the error "DB Error: unknown error" and I don't see anything in the Apache error logs.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this and see the actual error? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM logs? This errors are logged there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place.

Check your PHP logs on your webserver.

Check the civicrm logs in /civicrm/ConfigAndLog or wherever you have configured that folder.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a Python person by trade so wasn't sure where the logs would show up. I do see the full error now so I'll ask it as a separate question in case other people have seen this same error as opposed to turning this into something other than how it started. Appreciate the tip!